# Axis scaling in matlab

Tags: matlab

I was trying to set my plot axes "tight" using the following simple command in Matlab-

```
axis tight
```

which can also be done using-

```
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])
```

But by doing this, I found that a few my data points falling on the top of all axes as you can see here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vaUhVQVFOaTJKc1E/edit?usp=sharing

However, when I generate the same figure without the tight command, it looks even worse because too much space on both sides as you may see here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vZ0JZR0JZYmhIeVU/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to know if there's any function in Matlab that would help me to represent this scatter plot close to the tight scenario without letting any of my data points falling on any of the axis. say, 5% space on all sides. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just provide for the space manually:

```
[xmin, xmax] = xlim;
[ymin, ymax] = ylim;

x_tol = (xmax-xmin)*0.05;    %(5%) tolerance
y_tol = (ymax-ymin)*0.05;    %(5%) tolerance

axis([xmin-x_tol xmax+x_tol ymin-y_tol ymax+y_tol])
```

Comment: thanks ... if there is really no simple command, I would have tried something like this :)

Comment: @ToNoY: Happy to help. :) I myself have always felt that this should be an in-built functionality.